# How to extract map data for iphone app?

Tags: iphone, web-services, web, dictionary

I have a website with a [map and lat/long points for poker games](http://www.pokerdiy.com/find-poker-games.aspx).

I am outsourcing an iphone/android (using Appcelerator I think) app to show this data on a mobile map.

The part I need help on is HOW To expose this data to the client?! It's a DotNetNuke site (C#/SQL)

I think I have to write a webservice that queries the game table on the website and exposes something - but I don't know what format the dataset needs to be in or how to handle the reads (I assume the user goes to a location on the map and it asks for all the games with a distance x from this point - I assume I have to code that into my webservice so I am sending a small dataset?

Any tips appreciated - I don't know much about mapping or iphone clients!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in the end I used the WCF DNN series from GoodDogs - http://www.gooddogs.com/Blog/tabid/97/EntryId/5/WCF-Series-Part-4-Adding-a-REST-interface-to-your-Service.aspx to make REST services.

I used some SQL on the web to return the distance between 2 points (lat/long) and then the iphone app passes in the distance based on the zoom level.

It's all working well - I can elaborate if anyone needs more info...